# Python jupyter notebook and class variable scope

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two classes (A.py and B.py) defined as following

```
class AA():
   def __init__(self):
        self.myvar="MSG from AA"
    def getvarA(self):
        return self.myvar
    def setvarA(self,val):
        self.myvar = var
```

```
import A as a
class BB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.e = a.AA()
    def setvarB(self,msg):
        self.e.setvarA(msg)
```

In my jupyter notebook I do

```
import A as a
import B as b
va=a.AA()
vb=b.BB()
print(va.getvarA()) # print MSG from AA as expected
vb.setvarB('new msg')
print(va.getvarA()) # still print MSG from AA and I would like to have 'new msg'
```

How can I update va using B method (I know that from my notebook doing va.setvarA('new msg') is doing the job) ?

Answer (score 0):

`va=a.AA()` makes an instance of `AA()` and `vb=b.BB()` makes a new instance of `AA()` within `BB()` so when you do `vb.setvarB` it sets the msg of the instance `self.e` not `va`. to update an instance of `AA` using `BB`, the instance of `AA` would need to be inside `BB`. So you could do `vb=b.BB()`and `va=vb.e`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `vb` has no relation to `va`. There is nothing reasonable you can do to `vb` that will change `va`, because `vb` has no knowledge of `va`.

You need to give `va` to `vb` so it can manipulate it. This can be done simply by giving it to `vb`'s initializer when creating `vb`:

```
class BB():
    def __init__(self, existing_aa):
        # Use the existing passed-in instance instead of creating a new one
        self.e = existing_aa

. . .

va=a.AA()
vb=b.BB(va)  # "Tell" vb about va so it can use it
```